# write the value of a box into google spreadsheet instead of a 'text'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to copy and reorganise the value from one spread sheet to another one !
I think I'am pretty close to what I want, but just need some help.
so far I have done this :

```
function example2() {
  var Cop = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GO");
  var LP = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("0_Test-LISTE PROJETS");

  var valueRange = LP.getRange('A4:V4').getValues();
  Cop.getRange('A1:V1').setValues(valueRange);//just to test that I'am really able to capture the value from sheet "var LP"

  Cop.getRange('A2:F6').setValues([
  ['A4', 'H4', 'J4', 'Q4', 'U4', 'color red'],//project lenght
  ['A4', 'H4', 'J4', 'Q4', 'R4', 'color BLUE'],//research lenght
  ['A4', 'H4', 'J4', 'R4', 'R4 + 7days', 'color white'],//waiting for client
  ['A4', 'H4', 'J4', 'R4 + 7days', 'T4', 'color green'],//production time
  ['A4', 'H4', 'J4', 'T4', 'U4', 'color purple']//installation on site
  ]);
  debugger;
}
```

Unfortunately, I'am writing the text "A4" "H4"... in my boxes instead of writing the value from the box 'A4' and 'H4' from the "var LP"
I was thinking that I will easely find an answer on google, I don't know if I'am not using the good keywords... but I don't !

I guess that it is a simple question, but it will help me a lot !
(I know that there other issues that I will face, as dealing with the date value, coloring a box... But as a begining write the value will be a good start)

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to do some Logger.log. Like Logger.log(valueRange) to understand how data is stored.

I believe the code bellow does what you want

```js
  Cop.getRange('A2:F6').setValues([
  [valueRange[0][0], valueRange[0][7], valueRange[0][9], valueRange[0][16], valueRange[0][20], 'color red'],//project lenght
  [valueRange[0][0], valueRange[0][7], valueRange[0][9], valueRange[0][16], valueRange[0][17], 'color BLUE'],//research lenght
  [valueRange[0][0], valueRange[0][7], valueRange[0][9], valueRange[0][17], valueRange[0][17] + ' 7days', 'color white'],//waiting for client
  [valueRange[0][0], valueRange[0][7], valueRange[0][9], valueRange[0][17] + ' 7days', valueRange[0][19], 'color green'],//production time
  [valueRange[0][0], valueRange[0][7], valueRange[0][9], valueRange[0][19], valueRange[0][20], 'color purple']//installation on site
  ]);
```